# Formatting values using angular number format filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, format

As per the angular number format filter, if I give this

```
       $scope.numberExpression =123.45;

      {{ numberExpression | number : 2}} // returns 123.45
```

and if it is $scope.numberExpression =123;

```
     {{ numberExpression | number : 2}} // returns 123.00
```

But I dont want the 00 appended there . Is there a way to do this by using number filter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{numberExpression | number : ((numberExpression % 1 === 0) ? 0 : 2)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use number than `number:2` [`Plunkr Demo`](http://plnkr.co/edit/NxiPBcxf6te1KwgPuzWX?p=preview)

```
{{numberExpression  | number}}
```

```js
 angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 123.00;
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="numberFilterExample">

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter number: <input ng-model='val'><br>
  First example: <span id='number-default'> {{ val | number : 2}}</span><br>
  Second Example: <span>{{val | number}}</span>
</div>
</body>
```